# Rails: find the relationship name of an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

Assume we have this relationship:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'company_address_id'
  has_one :overseas_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'overseas_address_id'
end
```

If I `pry` within a **new** Address instance, is it possible to return `:company_address` or `:overseas_address`?

Fields are the same, but I want to do different validations.

Yes, there are alternative ways of solving the problem, but I'm more interested into whether finding the name of the relationship is actually possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have corresponding belong_to: in your Address model, then try `Address.reflect_on_all_associations(belongs_to)` 
it will return a collection of `ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection` which will have different `name` (depending on your belong_to)

In order to check instance you should mark your belong_tos as `inverse_of: :put_corresponding_association`, your has_one as inverse_of belong_tos and then you can check corresponding methods (generated by belong_tos) for presence of parent Company object

The idea is assume an Address as

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'company_address_id', inverse_of: :company_address
  belongs_to :oversea, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'overseas_address_id', inverse_of: :overseas_address
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'company_address_id', inverse_of: :company
  has_one :overseas_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'overseas_address_id', inverse_of: :oversea
end
```

and you create address as `address = company.overseas_address.new`

then

```
address.company == nil
address.oversea == company
```

Comment: http://viget.com/extend/identifying-foreign-key-dependencies-from-activerecordbase-classes here it is explained more

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see how this could work for a record in the database.

But not for a new instance?

Comment: Yep. I have `:inverse_of` in my belongs to. So in my address I can look at the corresponding company. But this doesn't give me any hint as to whether the address I'm currently interacting with is the standard address or the overseas address. Both can be created as nested attributes when the company is created. Does that help to explain my issue? Again – thanks for the reply.

Comment: i missed that you should have mirrored inverse_of on your has_one

Comment: How you create an instance of Address?